# didSelectRowAtIndexPath; UITapGestureRecognizer; custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a trouble w/ passing tap from table cell to `tableView` or speaking easy `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` isn't called.

I create custom `UITableViewCell`. It has two gesture recognizers

```
UIGestureRecognizer* panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
panRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
panRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

UIGestureRecognizer* tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
return YES;
}
```

But problem in spite of `cancelsTouchesInView=NO` `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not called.
Moreover I turned off interaction of all object inside of cell. Like

```
userInteractionEnabled = NO
```

But it doesn't help. It seems that tableview doesn't get touch... 
On the other hand inside cell gesture recognizers work well.

Does anybody have any ideas what is the reason why `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` not to work? 
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** it seems that problem are not in `UIGestureRecognizer`. I tried to remove them both, but it doesn't help. `UITableView` get pan gestures (because of working scrolling), but tap gestures disappeared... 
 **Is there any way to debug gestures event?**

Answer (score 2):

Every time you need to define custom intractable elements in TableViewCell you need to write protocol UITableViewCellDelegate and assign table as delegate of every cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomTableViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.delegate = self;

    . . . . . . . 
 }


- (void) tableViewCell:(UITableViewCell*)tableViewCell gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint locationInCell = [gestureRecognizer locationInView: tableViewCell];

    . . . . . . .
}
```

Here *type* is enum of interaction types - tap or pan.

Then you need to call this protocol method in your handlePan and handleTap cell methods with appropriate type.

Comment: actually I've though about such approach, but I suppose the should be another easier way. For example cell's pan gesture recognizer pass events to uitableview. I could see it because of tableview scrolling...

Comment: One more variant is to find tableView as parent view of cell. It should be self.superview or self.superview.superview depending on iOS version. And then call didSelectRowAtIndexPath directly. But in this case you need to pass indexPath to every cell as property to have a callback with correct indexPath.

Comment: To be honest, I've already implemented exactly this option :) But question is still opened. Where is this Tap event???

Comment: I mean what object get this event.

Comment: Delegate described can return tableViewCell and recognizer itself. And I think you mainly need a point of touch event (object + event). Use locationInView: method to get the point.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I want to know what object (cell, tableview, scroll view, Tim Cook or ANB :) ) is get this weird event. I could caught event in my cell but when I passed it (gestureRecognizerShouldBegin() return NO;), someone else should received it. I suppose it have to be UITableView but it doesn't (otherwise why there is not didSelectRowAtIndexPath). OR by other words why this passing event doesn't work properly...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
  if ([gestureRecognizer view] isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]
       return NO;
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: UIGestureRecognizer is belonged UITableViewCell. This condition is always true.

Comment: Where are you adding gesture to your cell? and why do you do this?

Comment: @user3124812 Well. According to your point, you want to call two delegate in one touch? Am I right?

Comment: they are both in awakeFromNib(). Pan gesture is for horizontal scrolling of cell, Tap gesture is to define tapping on cell...

Comment: Also, gestureRecognizerShouldBegin() should return NO to pass event to next object... and YES to catch it.